# Difference between Object and object

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c#: difference between “System.Object” and “object”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017282/c-difference-between-system-object-and-object)

Hello,

In C# there are Object and object types. They seem to have the same functionnality, so what is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is none. C# provides synonyms for the primitives defined by the CLR. System.String -> string, System.Int64 -> long, System.Object -> object, etc.

Answer (score 14):

No difference.

object is a synomym of System.Object

It is there to allow old users to not get totally confused when they moved from an older system to this.

Comment: What do you mean by old users? The only people I've ever seen use `Object` instead of `object` are Java programmers :)

Comment: That's what I mean. People are used to use "object" so to not force them to use "Object", they still have "object"

Comment: C# devs that started deving back on asp.net 2 and before. Every object or int I ran into was Object or Int32.

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe they are different, its like the difference between System.Int32 and int... they are the same essentially.

Answer (score 7):

None.

> The object type is an alias for System.Object in the .NET Framework. You can assign values of any type to variables of type object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c%28VS.71%29.aspx