# Remove Null from 2D Array

Tags: c#

I have a 2D array object fixed Size

```
object[,] = new object[1,50];
```

But Some times some sections of this null which i don't want in my Operation.
I wanted to Remove Nulls from 2D Array.

Where I couldn't find Remove Function with this. I don't want any loop to check each index.

How to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You did't use any identifier for the array.

Comment: 1. Im not sure how you can have a 0 column 2d array and 2. every element will be null since you havent initialized anything. 3. @MeysamTolouee - they [*are* the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3070628/1324033)

Answer (score 3):

An array is fixed size; you cannot "remove" *anything*. You can *replace* values with other values, via the indexer - but frankly I would say that `null` is the classic "doesn't have a value" for something we only know as `object`.

So you have a few options:

- if the problem is borders: create the array with the correct size so that there are no borders
- or initialize all the values to non-null values at the start
- or loop over the cells and replace null values with non-values at your convenience