# What is the diferrence between object and Object

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c#: difference between “System.Object” and “object”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017282/c-difference-between-system-object-and-object)

What is the diferrence between object and Object

Comment: As new user you are welcomed here, but consider that probability of  someone already had been asking your question and gathering the answer is very very high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are CLR types, as `System.Object` `System.Int32` etc. These are common for all .Net languages some of these types have C# aliases, that is, there are keywords in C# like `object`, `string`, `int` etc. These are specific to C# but are treated exactly as the CLR analogs

Answer (score 4):

There is no differrence.

From [object (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> The object type is an alias for Object
>   in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

`object` in C# is an alias for the .NET class [`System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx). You can use them interchangeably in C# code.