# Why is nameof(object) not allowed?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, nameof

In C# 6.0 you can write this:

```
var instance = default(object);
var type = typeof(object);
```

They have the same result of:

```
var instance = default(System.Object);
var type = typeof(System.Object);
```

But you can't write this:

```
var name = nameof(object);
```

It generates the following error:

> Invalid expression term 'object'.

But you can still write this:

```
var name = nameof(System.Object);
```

Why `nameof(object)` does not compile?

Comment: Try: `nameof(Object)` instead. `nameof()` doesn't work on synonyms, only on the original classnames.

Comment: @CodeCaster, to get the class `Object`'s name as string

Comment: @CodeCaster Jeroen is right. Try it if you don't believe it.

Comment: @CodeCaster also on classnames. I use it for logging purposes. Whenever I rename a class, this will be changed to.. Same applies to `nameof(int)` vs `nameof(Int32)`

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. It's a perfectly valid question, if not a bit short. If anything, it goes against the common idea that `Object` and `object` are entirely interchangeable. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017282/c-difference-between-system-object-and-object). This question shows that in fact, they are *not* the same.

Comment: @Jeroen alright, TIL.

Comment: @Rob agree there. The difference is that `object` is a synonym for `Object` and `nameof()` doesn't work on synonyms.

Comment: `object` is a *keyword* in the C# language.  Keywords are rather a big deal to compilers, they disambiguate syntax and help generate good error messages.  But with the hang-up that keywords are not identifiers so nameof() can't work.

Comment: @HansPassant how can keywords "help generate good error messages?"

Comment: Keywords are the rock-solid foundations upon which a language is built.  The parts of a statement that have a completely unambiguous meaning and the parser can rely on to mean only one thing.  If a parser can't rely on such guarantees then it has to guess what the programmer intended.  Guesses never produce good error messages, it might guess wrong and send the programmer into a rabbit hole.  It would technically not be impossible for the compiler to still recognize `object` in the specific case of parsing the nameof operand.  It would however greatly uglify the expression parser.

Comment: @Hans you mean like ideone (Mono)'s _"CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)`, expecting `.`"_ after `nameof(object)`? :)

Comment: Yes, good example :)  Mono treats it like an identifier instead of a keyword, tsk, tsk.

Comment: _"It would however greatly uglify the expression parser"_ @HansPassant are you saying that adding the recognition of keywords in the `nameof()` statement would have slowed down the parsing of the code? I'm not expert of low-level stuffs like compiler parsing, so it's a honest question.

Comment: Speed is not an issue.  The expression parser would have to accept keywords like `object`, `string`, `int`, etc.  But only in the specific case of it being used to parse the nameof operand.   And still deal with the wonky cases like `object int` and produce a decent error message for them.  The expression parser is one of the most difficult parts of a compiler, there is lots of expressive power in a language like C#.  The less special cases, the lower the risk that it accidentally accepts malformed code or spits out a bad diagnostic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that `object` is a synonym for the class `Object` and `nameof()` doesn't work on synonyms.

Same applies to `nameof(int)` vs `nameof(Int32)`

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn986596.aspx "The following are worth mentioning that produce errors: *predefined types (for example, int or void)*"

Comment: @Rob well that's the reference, not the specification. Technically, `System.Object` is a predefined simple type, and `object` its alias, so neither should work according to that description...