# Why doesn't nameof work on synonymous?

Tags: c#, nameof, type-synonyms

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421961/why-is-nameofobject-not-allowed) I learned that the `nameof()` operator, introduced in C# 6.0, does not work on synonymous. So you can write `nameof(System.Object)` but not `nameof(object)`.

Now, there are 2 other similar operators, `typeof()` and `default()`, and they work perfectly on synonymous. You can write:

```
default(object);
default(int);
typeof(string);
typeof(long);
```

as well as:

```
default(Object);
default(Int32);
typeof(String);
typeof(Int64);
```

and the results are the same.

I guess that it would have been possible to build the `nameof()` operator to operate with synonymous too.

So the question is: WHY it was not implemented to work with `object`, `string`, `int`, etc.? Is my guess wrong (i.e. it's impossible to implement)? Or was it a *design* choice?

Comment: Unless one of the language designers answers this, any answers to this question will be primarily opinion-based...

Comment: Simply: `typeof` and `default` are working with type, while [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) works with more than that. The real question is here why **you think** `nameof` should work with types similarly to e.g. `typeof`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, yes, probably you're right... do you think I should change the question into something like _"what are the pros and cons of prohibiting `nameof()` on synonymous?"_? Would it be less opinion-based? Or do you know how can we have the confirmation from some C# guy? :-)

Comment: You can't really make this the kind of question to ask on StackOverflow, since it can't be objectively answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a *design* choice.

`typeof()` operator returns a `Type`. Since `object` and `System.Object` express the same exact `Type`, there is no problem in writing `typeof(object)`.

The same applies to `default()`: it is `null` in both cases (or `0` or whatever).

Now, for `nameof()`, the context is a bit harder.

Pretend that `nameof(object)` is allowed. What should it return?

1. `"object"`. But now the result is different from `nameof(System.Object)`, and it makes no sense, given that the class is the same.
2. `"Object"` uppercase, the same as `nameof(System.Object)`. But now we have a strange exception on the rule: `nameof()` returns the exact string representation of the expression passed as parameter... except `object` (and the other synonymous). This can cause subtle issues, for example I might give for sure that `nameof(object)` returns `"object"` since `nameof(Table)` returns `"Table"` and `nameof(MyComponent.SomeProperty)` returns `"SomeProperty"`, and so on.

Making `nameof()` not available on synonymous definitely resolved the ambiguity.

Comment: But your argment about `the result is different from nameof(System.Object)` also applies to `typeof(object).FullName` ("System.Object") and `typeof(Object).FullName` (also "System.Object") and `typeof(System.Object).FullName` (again, "System.Object").

Comment: @MatthewWatson I can't see how it applies also to `typeof().FullName`. `typeof()` is about a `Type`, not a "string representation", and the `Type` under `object` or `System.Object` is _exactly_ the same. Even further, the property is called `FullName`. The "`Full`" qualifier avoids any possible residual ambiguity.