# how to change from char data type to string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, types, char

I have this code and it shows an error when I try to make the letter uppercase

```
String word = "animals are my best friend";
Int wordLength = word.Length;
Random rando = new Random();
Int genRan = rando.Next(1, wordLength);
Char randomLettersf = word[genRan];
String upercase = randomLettersf.toUpper;
```

this is my first question so sorry for the formatting errors and I am new to coding. i am trying to make a random sentence into randomcase.
thank you

Comment: https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/1330430245384679424?s=20

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- .NET uses `PascalCase` not `camelCase` for members.

  - So `toUpper` is *wrong*.
  - Also, your variable should be named `upperCase`, not `upercase`.
- .NET's base library has its fair share of inconsistently-designed APIs: while `String` has `ToUpper` as an instance method, the `Char.ToUpper` method is `static`.

  - Yes, it's an annoying *design bug* in .NET.

So change the last line of your code to this:

```
Char uppercase = Char.ToUpper( randomLettersf );
```

If you want it as a `String` rather than as a `Char` then do this:

```
String uppercase = Char.ToUpper( randomLettersf ).ToString();
```

Comment: thank you, very much. I really apreciate this

Comment: also, you should prefer to use the languages inbuilt types string and char as opposed to String and Char.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I used to work on Visual Studio at Microsoft, and **I prefer** to use the CLR type names, not the C# alias names :)

Comment: that's nice, but that is really uncommon and really shouldn't be recommended

Comment: @KeithNicholas With respect, that's your subjective opinion. What's your authoritative basis for what should be "recommended" or not? I'll remind you that the latest versions of Visual Studio have an option to auto-format code to use CLR type names instead of C# alias names.

Comment: there is no authoritative basis, but it has been hashed out a number of times in a number of places......  on SO, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981434/can-anyone-give-me-a-really-good-reason-to-use-clr-type-names-instead-of-c-sharp